# Java: KeyListener not functioning

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

I'm working on my idle game, and I'm starting to add in an adventure side to it, but it's not working. I had it to where it would flicker on and off the screen, but when I started working on it more, it started to not work.

Here is the threaded code:

```
thread = new Thread(this);
IH = new ImageHandler(this);
listener = new Listener(this);
removeEntity = new ArrayList<>();
addEntity = new HashMap<>();

frame = new JFrame("IDLE");
frame.add(this);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.addWindowListener(listener);
frame.addMouseListener(listener);
frame.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
frame.addKeyListener(listener);
frame.pack();

Image bgBase = IH.getImg("background");

frame.setVisible(true);
WIDTH = frame.getWidth();
HEIGHT = frame.getHeight();

background = IH.getBG();
adv = new Adventures(this);
//Stuff here to load in the variables and entity data
start();
```

Now, here are my start and stops:

```
private synchronized void start() {
    thread.start();
}
public synchronized void stop() {
    save();
    frame.setVisible(false);
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}
```

And now my "run" class (because of the Thread):

```
    public void run() {

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;//60 times per second
    double delta = 0;
    requestFocus();
    while(frame.isVisible()) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta = delta + ((now-lastTime) / ns);
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1)//Make sure update is only happening 60 times a second
        {
            //handles all of the logic restricted time
            update();
            delta--;
        }
        this.repaint();//displays to the screen unrestricted time
    }
}
```

If you need more code, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you actually implemented on of the interface methods the KeyListener addresses.
I see the declaration and binding in your code `frame.addKeyListener(listener);` but there should be something like a `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`method.

Comment: My Listener has this:

    `@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  int key = e.getKeyCode();
  if(main.PAGE.equals("idle")){
   if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
    main.stop();
   }else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    main.SEEN = !main.SEEN;
   }
  }
 }`